# Powershell: Export User Rights Assignment

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, batch-file

I'm new to PowerShell (PS). Currently I'm using windows server 2012 and I'm interested to know whether there is any way to export `User Rights Assignment` into a txt file. I tried

```
secedit /export /areas USER_RIGHTS /cfg d:\policies.txt
```

The above should should export it.

So, I get this: [Current Output](http://pastebin.com/Cb3afzKW).
Is there any way to export `User Rights Assignment` and make it  look like (even with using batch files): [Expected Output](http://pastebin.com/P3xKFrnS).

**P.S**
Is There anyway to output those values in console? So i would be enable to redirect them to a txt file.

Comment: Please edit the description and clearly explain the difference between the two links you have pasted. That will make the problem clear to the readers. Even when the link is removed, readers will still have access to the problem description.

Comment: Sorry link got changed in edit

Comment: I could probably try to help you but my company blocks all file download sites so I can't view any of the links you posted.

Comment: should just post them?

Comment: @jonjoli - See my updated answer.

Comment: Excuse me. Could you give me indications on how I can get the "Expected Output" that you posted at [this link](http://pastebin.com/P3xKFrnS). Give specific details, please. TIA!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a PowerShell script that outputs usable objects with translated names and SIDs:

```
#requires -version 2

# Fail script if we can't find SecEdit.exe
$SecEdit = Join-Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath([Environment+SpecialFolder]::System)) "SecEdit.exe"
if ( -not (Test-Path $SecEdit) ) {
  Write-Error "File not found - '$SecEdit'" -Category ObjectNotFound
  exit
}

# LookupPrivilegeDisplayName Win32 API doesn't resolve logon right display
# names, so use this hashtable
$UserLogonRights = @{
  "SeBatchLogonRight"                 = "Log on as a batch job"
  "SeDenyBatchLogonRight"             = "Deny log on as a batch job"
  "SeDenyInteractiveLogonRight"       = "Deny log on locally"
  "SeDenyNetworkLogonRight"           = "Deny access to this computer from the network"
  "SeDenyRemoteInteractiveLogonRight" = "Deny log on through Remote Desktop Services"
  "SeDenyServiceLogonRight"           = "Deny log on as a service"
  "SeInteractiveLogonRight"           = "Allow log on locally"
  "SeNetworkLogonRight"               = "Access this computer from the network"
  "SeRemoteInteractiveLogonRight"     = "Allow log on through Remote Desktop Services"
  "SeServiceLogonRight"               = "Log on as a service"
}

# Create type to invoke LookupPrivilegeDisplayName Win32 API
$Win32APISignature = @'
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern bool LookupPrivilegeDisplayName(
  string systemName,
  string privilegeName,
  System.Text.StringBuilder displayName,
  ref uint cbDisplayName,
  out uint languageId
);
'@
$AdvApi32 = Add-Type advapi32 $Win32APISignature -Namespace LookupPrivilegeDisplayName -PassThru

# Use LookupPrivilegeDisplayName Win32 API to get display name of privilege
# (except for user logon rights)
function Get-PrivilegeDisplayName {
  param(
    [String] $name
  )
  $displayNameSB = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder 1024
  $languageId = 0
  $ok = $AdvApi32::LookupPrivilegeDisplayName($null, $name, $displayNameSB, [Ref] $displayNameSB.Capacity, [Ref] $languageId)
  if ( $ok ) {
    $displayNameSB.ToString()
  }
  else {
    # Doesn't lookup logon rights, so use hashtable for that
    if ( $UserLogonRights[$name] ) {
      $UserLogonRights[$name]
    }
    else {
      $name
    }
  }
}

# Outputs list of hashtables as a PSObject
function Out-Object {
  param(
    [System.Collections.Hashtable[]] $hashData
  )
  $order = @()
  $result = @{}
  $hashData | ForEach-Object {
    $order += ($_.Keys -as [Array])[0]
    $result += $_
  }
  New-Object PSObject -Property $result | Select-Object $order
}

# Translates a SID in the form *S-1-5-... to its account name;
function Get-AccountName {
  param(
    [String] $principal
  )
  if ( $principal[0] -eq "*" ) {
    $sid = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($principal.Substring(1))
    $sid.Translate([Security.Principal.NTAccount])
  }
  else {
    $principal
  }
}

$TemplateFilename = Join-Path ([IO.Path]::GetTempPath()) ([IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName())
$LogFilename = Join-Path ([IO.Path]::GetTempPath()) ([IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName())
$StdOut = & $SecEdit /export /cfg $TemplateFilename /areas USER_RIGHTS /log $LogFilename
if ( $LASTEXITCODE -eq 0 ) {
  Select-String '^(Se\S+) = (\S+)' $TemplateFilename | Foreach-Object {
    $Privilege = $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
    $Principals = $_.Matches[0].Groups[2].Value -split ','
    foreach ( $Principal in $Principals ) {
      Out-Object `
        @{"Privilege" = $Privilege},
        @{"PrivilegeName" = Get-PrivilegeDisplayName $Privilege},
        @{"Principal" = Get-AccountName $Principal}
    }
  }
}
else {
  $OFS = ""
  Write-Error "$StdOut"
}
Remove-Item $TemplateFilename,$LogFilename -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: sorry for late response but that gives the same output as "secedit /export /areas USER_RIGHTS /cfg d:\policies.txt"

Comment: It outputs the data as objects, not as text, so no, the output is not "the same". Perhaps you need to clarify your question.

Comment: how to make it ouput as txt?

Comment: What do you mean? Please update your question with what you want the output to look like (no links please - please paste an example directly into your question).

Comment: You are in luck in this case. I think I understand. See updated answer.

Comment: I know this is a novice's dumb question: how can I get the "GUI output" that the OP refers as Expected Output? Give specific details please, I had never used `secedit` nor any equivalent application before... TIA

Comment: Documentation on secedit is [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490997.aspx). The script I wrote runs `secedit /export` and "re-outputs" it as PowerShell objects.

Comment: See updated answer; it uses LookupPrivilegeDisplayName API to resolve the privilege display names (except for the user logon rights; we still use a hashtable for that). Note that this output is superior to the GUI because it outputs one principal name per privilege rather than a comma-delimited list.

Comment: Excuse me, perhaps I was not clear enough... I know that running the `secedit /export` command described at your link gives me the ["Current Output"](http://pastebin.com/Cb3afzKW) posted by the OP (the one that start in "[Unicode]" line). However, I want NOT such output (nor any equivalent one)! I want the ["Expected Output"](http://pastebin.com/P3xKFrnS), the one that start in "Policy  Security Setting" line. How can I get _such output_? Note: it don't matters if the output from your script is "superior to the GUI". I am _not_ using PowerShell. I just want to know how to get the GUI output...

Comment: Go ahead and start a new question. (I don't have access to the pastebin links, so that's a non-starter that shouldn't be in the question anyway.) I would also recommend learning PowerShell; your time investment will be well rewarded.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to Eric's change i also needed to add a try catch to one of the functions in Bill_Stewart's post. if the SID being translated is from an object that no longer exists this will return the SID instead of sending an error for translate.

```
# Translates a SID in the form *S-1-5-... to its account name;
function Get-AccountName {
  param(
    [String] $principal
  )
  if ( $principal[0] -eq "*" ) {
    $sid = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($principal.Substring(1))
    Try {$out = $sid.Translate([Security.Principal.NTAccount])}
    catch
        {
        $out = $principal
        }
    $out
  }
  else {
    $principal
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Great script overall. Thank you for your efforts. One change I needed to make however to get it to output all principals assigned a right was to change the regex to '^(Se\S+) = (.+)' so that principals that were already resolved  with a space in the name such as 'Domain users' were matched. Before that it would just report 'Domain.'

To save the output to a file, add a >> filename after the closing bracket of the last foreach-object
Ex:
    }
    } >> 'outFile.txt'

or to output as delimited file (e.g., csv) use the following:

} | convertto-csv -delimiter '~' -notypeinformation >> 'outFile.txt'

Hope this helps.