# Powershell:In user right assignment how to get same output from script as from gui

Tags: windows, shell, security, powershell, batch-file

I'm new with powershell and I have this question. I exported list from gui and it looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/P3xKFrnS)

```
Policy  Security Setting
Access Credential Manager as a trusted caller  
Access this computer from the network   Everyone,Administrators,Users,Backup Operators
Act as part of the operating system
Add workstations to domain 
Adjust memory quotas for a process  LOCAL SERVICE,NETWORK SERVICE,Administrators
Allow log on locally    Administrators,Users,Backup Operators
Allow log on through Remote Desktop Services    Administrators,Remote Desktop Users
Back up files and directories   Administrators,Backup Operators
Bypass traverse checking    Everyone,LOCAL SERVICE,NETWORK SERVICE,Administrators,Users,Backup Operators,Window Manager\Window Manager Group
Change the system time  LOCAL SERVICE,Administrators
Change the time zone    LOCAL SERVICE,Administrators
... output truncated....
```

but from script I run
 `secedit /export /areas USER_RIGHTS /cfg d:\policies.txt`
code which gives me back [this](http://pastebin.com/Cb3afzKW)

```
[Unicode]
Unicode=yes
[Privilege Rights]
SeNetworkLogonRight = *S-1-1-0,*S-1-5-32-544,*S-1-5-32-545,*S-1-5-32-551
SeTcbPrivilege = Pearl,*S-1-5-21-1042109134-4285797005-3901271436-1004,*S-1-5-21-1042109134-4285797005-3901271436-1006,*S-1-5-21-1042109134-4285797005-3901271436-1007,nx
SeBackupPrivilege = Pearl,*S-1-5-32-544,*S-1-5-32-551
SeChangeNotifyPrivilege = *S-1-1-0,*S-1-5-19,*S-1-5-20,*S-1-5-32-544,*S-1-5-32-545,*S-1-5-32-551
SeSystemtimePrivilege = *S-1-5-19,*S-1-5-32-544
SeCreatePagefilePrivilege = *S-1-5-32-544
SeDebugPrivilege = *S-1-5-32-544
SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege = *S-1-5-32-544
SeAuditPrivilege = *S-1-5-19,*S-1-5-20
SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege = *S-1-5-19,*S-1-5-20,*S-1-5-21-1042109134-4285797005-3901271436-1004,*S-1-5-21-1042109134-4285797005-3901271436-1006,*S-1-5-21-1042109134-4285797005-3901271436-1007,nx,*S-1-5-32-544
... output truncated....
```

So is there any way to parse this data and get the same output from GUI by PowerShell or batch file or any other way?

Comment: This in theory could be done.... You have security objects that need to be converted. There is a lot of string replacements that could go on here. All of the policies would have to be changed from their names to human friendly descriptions. I do not know if such a reference exists that you could use (looking now for myself). Either way this reads like a code writing request which is off-topic for SO. Is there anything you have tried in figuring this out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell: Export User Rights Assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35344825/powershell-export-user-rights-assignment)

Comment: See my answer in the [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35344825/).

Answer (score 2):

As I understand this problem, you want to translate the text output produced by `secedit /export /areas USER_RIGHTS /cfg d:\policies.txt` command into the equivalent output "exported from gui". I borrowed the list of equivalences from the answer at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35344825/powershell-export-user-rights-assignment), added a list of equivalences for each one of the terms and used they to write a Batch file that should perform such translation. This is the code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the translation array of items
for %%a in (
   "SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege=Replace a process-level token"
   "SeAuditPrivilege=Generate security audits"
   "SeBackupPrivilege=Back up files and directories"
   "SeBatchLogonRight=Log on as a batch job"
   "SeChangeNotifyPrivilege=Bypass traverse checking"
   "SeCreateGlobalPrivilege=Create global objects"
   "SeCreatePagefilePrivilege=Create a pagefile"
   "SeCreatePermanentPrivilege=Create permanent shared objects"
   "SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege=Create symbolic links"
   "SeCreateTokenPrivilege=Create a token object"
   "SeDebugPrivilege=Debug programs"
   "SeDenyBatchLogonRight=Deny logon as a batch file"
   "SeDenyInteractiveLogonRight=Deny local logon"
   "SeDenyNetworkLogonRight=Deny Access to this computer from the network"
   "SeDenyRemoteInteractiveLogonRight=Deny logon through terminal services"
   "SeDenyServiceLogonRight=Deny logon as a service"
   "SeEnableDelegationPrivilege=Enable computer and user accounts to be trusted for delegation"
   "SeImpersonatePrivilege=Impersonate a client after authentication"
   "SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege=Increase scheduling priority"
   "SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege=Adjust memory quotas for a process"
   "SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege=Increase a process working set"
   "SeInteractiveLogonRight=Log on locally"
   "SeLoadDriverPrivilege=Load and unload device drivers"
   "SeLockMemoryPrivilege=Lock pages in memory"
   "SeMachineAccountPrivilege=Add workstations to the domain"
   "SeManageVolumePrivilege=Manage the files on a volume"
   "SeNetworkLogonRight=Access this Computer from the Network"
   "SeProfileSingleProcessPrivilege=Profile a single process"
   "SeRelabelPrivilege=Modify an object label"
   "SeRemoteInteractiveLogonRight=Allow logon through terminal services"
   "SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege=Force shutdown from a remote system"
   "SeRestorePrivilege=Restore files and directories"
   "SeSecurityPrivilege=Manage auditing and security log"
   "SeServiceLogonRight=Logon as a service"
   "SeShutdownPrivilege=Shut down the system"
   "SeSyncAgentPrivilege=Synchronize directory service data"
   "SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege=Modify firmware environment values"
   "SeSystemProfilePrivilege=Profile system performance"
   "SeSystemTimePrivilege=Change the system time"
   "SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege=Take ownership of files or other objects"
   "SeTcbPrivilege=Act as part of the operating system"
   "SeTimeZonePrivilege=Change the time zone"
   "SeTrustedCredManAccessPrivilege=Access Credential Manager as a trusted caller"
   "SeUndockPrivilege=Remove computer from docking station"
   "SeUnsolicitedInputPrivilege=Read unsolicited data from a terminal device"
   ) do for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%b in (%%a) do (
      set "in[%%b]=%%c"
)

rem Define the translation array of terms
set "maxTerms=0"
for %%a in ("S-1-1-0=Everyone"
            "S-1-5-6=SERVICE"
            "S-1-5-19=LOCAL SERVICE"
            "S-1-5-20=NETWORK SERVICE"
            "S-1-5-32-544=Administrators"
            "S-1-5-32-545=Users"
            "S-1-5-32-551=Backup Operators"
            "S-1-5-32-559=Performance Log Users"
            "S-1-5-80-0=NT SERVICE\ALL SERVICES") do (
   for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%b in (%%a) do (
      set "term[*%%b]=%%c"
   )
   set /A "maxTerms+=1"
)

rem Process the input file and create the output array
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims== " %%a in (input.txt) do if defined in[%%a] (
   set "line="
   set "terms=%%b"
   for /L %%i in (1,1,%maxTerms%) do (
      for /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%c in ("!terms!") do (
         if defined term[%%c] set "line=!line!,!term[%%c]!"
         set "terms=%%d"
      )
   )
   if not defined line set "line=,"
   set "out[!in[%%a]!]=!line:~1!"
)

rem Show the output array
echo Policy Security Setting
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=[]=" %%a in ('set out[') do echo %%a  %%b
```

However, the output obtained from this program have several differences from the gui-exported output you show in the link. These differences may be caused because the equivalence terms in the original table are wrong, or because the command-text and gui-exported outputs you posted does not correspond to the same data. For example, in the command-text output there is this line: `SeTimeZonePrivilege = *S-1-5-19,*S-1-5-32-544,*S-1-5-32-545` that my program show as `Change the time zone LOCAL SERVICE,Administrators,Users`, but that in the exported-gui output appears this way: `Change the time zone    LOCAL SERVICE,Administrators`. Why the "Users" part does not appear in the gui-exported output? I have not means to know the answer to this question, so I need additional data in order to complete this program.

Comment: What do you mean in additional data?

Comment: The data you posted in the gui-exported output does _not_ match the one you posted in the command-text output. Which one is the right one? I don't know! (I never used `secedit` command before). The purpose of my answer is to fulfill _your request_, so you must say if the output of my code is correct or not. You should run my program and then indicate me the modifications you want in the output that would do my code a correct solution.

Comment: you're code doesnt run it gives error `The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an expression`

Comment: Did you saved this code in a Batch file with .BAT extension? In the question you said: "is there any way to parse this data and get the same output from GUI by PowerShell or **batch file** or any other way?", the question include the `batch-file` tag, and I said in my answer: "and used these data to write a **Batch file** that should perform such translation. This is the code"