# Powershell: Exception calling translate with 1 argument

Tags: windows, shell, powershell

Hell. I'm new with powershell and I'm trying to write a program which would translate output from `secedit /export /areas USER_RIGHTS /cfg d:\policies.txt` (which exports user right assignment) to human readable eye. here is my code:

```
$output=@()
$temp = "c:\"
$file = "$temp\privs.txt"
[string] $readableNames

$process = [diagnostics.process]::Start("secedit.exe", "/export /cfg $file /areas USER_RIGHTS")
$process.WaitForExit()
$in = get-content $file

foreach ($line in $in) {
    if ($line.StartsWith("Se")) {
    $privilege = $line.substring(0,$line.IndexOf("=") - 1)
    switch ($privilege){
    "SeCreateTokenPrivilege " {$privilege = "Create a token object"}
    "SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege" {$privilege = "Replace a process-level token"}
    "SeLockMemoryPrivilege" {$privilege = "Lock pages in memory"}
    "SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege" {$privilege = "Adjust memory quotas for a process"}
    "SeUnsolicitedInputPrivilege" {$privilege = "Load and unload device drivers"}
    "SeMachineAccountPrivilege" {$privilege = "Add workstations to domain"}
    "SeTcbPrivilege" {$privilege = "Act as part of the operating system"}
    "SeSecurityPrivilege" {$privilege = "Manage auditing and the security log"}
    "SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege" {$privilege = "Take ownership of files or other objects"}
    "SeLoadDriverPrivilege" {$privilege = "Load and unload device drivers"}
    "SeSystemProfilePrivilege" {$privilege = "Profile system performance"}
    "SeSystemtimePrivilege" {$privilege = "Change the system time"}
    "SeProfileSingleProcessPrivilege" {$privilege = "Profile single process"}
    "SeCreatePagefilePrivilege" {$privilege = "Create a pagefile"}
    "SeCreatePermanentPrivilege" {$privilege = "Create permanent shared objects"}
    "SeBackupPrivilege" {$privilege = "Back up files and directories"}
    "SeRestorePrivilege" {$privilege = "Restore files and directories"}
    "SeShutdownPrivilege" {$privilege = "Shut down the system"}
    "SeDebugPrivilege" {$privilege = "Debug programs"}
    "SeAuditPrivilege" {$privilege = "Generate security audit"}
    "SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege" {$privilege = "Modify firmware environment values"}
    "SeChangeNotifyPrivilege" {$privilege = "Bypass traverse checking"}
    "SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege" {$privilege = "Force shutdown from a remote system"}
    "SeUndockPrivilege" {$privilege = "Remove computer from docking station"}
    "SeSyncAgentPrivilege" {$privilege = "Synchronize directory service data"}
    "SeEnableDelegationPrivilege" {$privilege = "Enable computer and user accounts to be trusted for delegation"}
    "SeManageVolumePrivilege" {$privilege = "Manage the files on a volume"}
    "SeImpersonatePrivilege" {$privilege = "Impersonate a client after authentication"}
    "SeCreateGlobalPrivilege" {$privilege = "Create global objects"}
    "SeTrustedCredManAccessPrivilege" {$privilege = "Access Credential Manager as a trusted caller"}
    "SeRelabelPrivilege" {$privilege = "Modify an object label"}
    "SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege" {$privilege = "Increase a process working set"}
    "SeTimeZonePrivilege" {$privilege = "Change the time zone"}
    "SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege" {$privilege = "Create symbolic links"}
    "SeDenyInteractiveLogonRight" {$privilege = "Deny local logon"}
    "SeRemoteInteractiveLogonRight" {$privilege = "Allow logon through Terminal Services"}
    "SeServiceLogonRight" {$privilege = "Logon as a service"}
    "SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege" {$privilege = "Increase scheduling priority"}
    "SeBatchLogonRight" {$privilege = "Log on as a batch job"}
    "SeInteractiveLogonRight" {$privilege = "Log on locally"}
    "SeDenyNetworkLogonRight" {$privilege = "Deny Access to this computer from the network"}
    "SeNetworkLogonRight" {$privilege = "Access this Computer from the Network"}
    "SeDenyBatchLogonRight" {$privilege = "Deny log on as a batch job"}
    "SeDenyServiceLogonRight" {$privilege = "Deny log on as a service"}
    "SeDenyRemoteInteractiveLogonRight" {$privilege = "Deny log on through Remote Desktop Services"}
 }

$sids = $line.substring($line.IndexOf("=") + 1,$line.Length - ($line.IndexOf("=") + 1))
$sids =  $sids.Trim() -split ","
$readableNames = ""
    foreach ($str in $sids){
            $str = $str.substring(1)
            $sid = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($str)
            $readableName = $sid.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])

            $readableNames = $readableNames + $readableName.Value + ", "
     }
$output += New-Object PSObject -Property @{            
    privilege       = $privilege               
    readableNames   = $readableNames.substring(0,($readableNames.Length - 1))
    #else            = $line."property" 
} 
}
}

$output
```

When I run this program It outputs a lot of errors saying `Exception calling translate with 1 argument` and `New-Object : Exception calling .ctor with 1 argument(s): value was invalid` but after that it also outputs the data I wanted. So How can I fix erros. There are many topics about this but none of them worked for me. Hope you can help, Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell: Export User Rights Assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35344825/powershell-export-user-rights-assignment)

Comment: We need the full exception (including the line that is executed etc.). Was this solved after implementing `Test-SID` (in your other question)?

Comment: See my answer in the [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35344825/).